# Issues Deploying Github Branch From Heroku

Tags: php, github, heroku

I have a PHP application that runs without issues on my local machine, as well as on Heroku. It is connected to a Github repo, from Heroku, and I am struggling with deploying a branch.

Whenever I click on "Deploy Branch," I get the error message below.

```
-----> App not compatible with buildpack: https://buildpack-registry.s3.amazonaws.com/buildpacks/heroku/php.tgz
       
 !     ERROR: Application not supported by this buildpack!
 !     
 !     The 'heroku/php' buildpack is set on this application, but was
 !     unable to detect a PHP codebase.
 !     
 !     A PHP app on Heroku requires a 'composer.json' at the root of
 !     the directory structure, or an 'index.php' for legacy behavior.
 !     
 !     If you are trying to deploy a PHP application, ensure that one
 !     of these files is present at the top level directory.
 !     
 !     If you are trying to deploy an application written in another
 !     language, you need to change the list of buildpacks set on your
 !     Heroku app using the 'heroku buildpacks' command.
 !     
 !     For more information, refer to the following documentation:
 !     https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/buildpacks
 !     https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/php-support#activation
       More info: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/buildpacks#detection-failure
 !     Push failed
```

I have read the error message and I have both the `composer.json` and `index.php` files. Below is the structure of my app:

```
my_project:
- vendor/
- .gitignore
- .env
- composer.json
- composer.lock
- index.php
- Procfile
```

Is there anything I am missing?

Comment: Do you have composer.json in the root folder or are they located in a subfolder (like "my_project")? The error message says: _"A PHP app on Heroku requires a 'composer.json' at the root of the directory structure"_

Comment: "my_project" is the root folder where all files are.

Comment: Are you uploading the folder `my_project` as well? If yes, then only upload the contents, not the folder since that will put your code in a sub folder (`my_project`) and not in the root (which is where the `my_project` folder is).

Comment: I have a directory named `Web Projects` in my home directory. This is where I keep all my projects. Now, I have created a new directory `my_project` for the project I am currently working on. So, `my_project` is the root directory/folder for this project where git was initialised and all files are kept. I push to Heroku from inside this directory.

Answer (score 0):

I forgot to come back and update this question, so here it is.

Unfortunately, I had not yet fully understood the flow between Github and Heroku. I had the Heroku git URL added as a remote on my local repo and I was committing/pushing code from my local machine to Heroku and expecting it to then go to Github. That is, however, not how it works.

I had to add a remote linking to the Github repo and push changes to it then deploy from there to Heroku - under the 'Deploy' tab on Heroku. That way, it works like a charm.